# how to get y axis values of multiple series in plotoption while using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am currently using Highcharts library for displaying data in graphical format.
In current scenario i need to show column chart(current values) with a line showing the average values for the corresponding column. also i need to show upward and downward arrows depending if the actual value is greater than the average value and downwards arrow otherwise.
i have average and actual values in 2 different series.

most of the things i have done however i am not able to get the values of actual vs average in the plotoption section of the highchart.
once i have these values, i can decide and show correct arrow over the column.

can someone help?

```
plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    shared:true,
                    formatter: function(args) {
        //trying to put condition here for the upward and downward arrow.                                 
        return '<div ><div class="tolerenceDown" ></div></div>';            
                    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sanket_bhalerao/fupggsy2/6/

Comment: How are you initially calculating the average? Are there multiple values that sum up to make the values for 1 column?

Comment: just like current values i wll get the average values from backend.

Comment: i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24178041/5691018) solution but it didnt work for me 
,fiddle for same
http://jsfiddle.net/89zyx/3/

Comment: So do you not need help with the averages, do you just need help with the arrows?

Comment: yes, more accurately checking if average series value vs actual series value.

Comment: I have had a look around the Highcharts API and came across this jsFiddleL http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/members/axis-setcompare/, where you can compare the value of series. This comes from this API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setCompare. Unfortunately I am unable to get it working but here's a few sources to look at :)

Comment: From this, you'll be able to write an `if` condition in the tooltip and display certain arrows (I suggest `.png`'s) as required

Comment: I have editted the fiddle to show you how to get access to corresponding average value, you can perform your calculations easily now. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fupggsy2/8/) is the fiddle.