# How to get series highlight on hover in highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

Highcharts has this neat feature when hovering over a bar in a column chart, the entire series is highlighted, best seen live [here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-negative):

[image]

In the R wrapper `highcharter` this does not work, why?

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = c('Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas')) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "John", data = c(5, 3, 4, 7, 2)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Jane", data = c(2, -2, -3, 2, 1)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Joe", data = c(3, 4, 4, -2, 5))

hc
```

[image]

Comment: Related question without a solution - [highcharter: Highlight points in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263285/highcharter-highlight-points-in-a-group?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Because current highcharter uses Highcharts **7.0.1**, but this series highlighting (officially called **inactive state**) exists since Highcharts **7.1.0** version. See the changelog here: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v7.1.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the development version from Github and this feature will work for you. The CRAN version is still referring the older version of Highcharts.

```
devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
```

https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter